# How to return to home activity on single backpressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I want to return to home activity on single backpressed and on double backpressed exit from app but it not working properly i had added code below kindly help me.

```
 if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) 
{
            replaceFragment(new HomeActivity());
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
```

kindly help me.

Comment: is "HomeActivity" a fragment?

Comment: yes its a fragment

Comment: anyone have any ideas please help me.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your Handler run method

```
            @Override
            public void run() {
                replaceFragment(new HomeActivity());
                ActivityName.super.onBackPressed();
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
```

**OR**
make else method like this

```
else{
replaceFragment(new HomeActivity());
            super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: which one you have implemented?

Comment: if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        }else

Comment: trying put log method inside else condition

Comment: can you add if and else conditions in comment so i can understand properly.

Comment: you should use first reply because second will not work if i put else condition on  if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) statement

Comment: can you put logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int BACK_PRESS = 76;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (BACK_PRESS == msg.what) {
            goBack();
        }
    }
};

private void goBack() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mHandler.hasMessages(BACK_PRESS)) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(BACK_PRESS);
        replaceFragment(new HomeActivity());
    } else {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(BACK_PRESS, 500); // Your activity will close after 500ms
    }
}
```

you can use handler in different way for your case.

Comment: what is msg.what ? in if condition

Comment: That is just the empty message we sent to handler using mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(BACK_PRESS, 500);.  This will create an empty message with "BACK_PRESS" as the "what" value.